# What are requirements for CompletionToken from BoostAsio?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

What are requirements for an "object" to be a CompletionToken in BoostAsio?
I read tutorial [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html), but didn't get what are requirements.

For example: how can I know whether I can pass some class as a CompletionToken to a function?

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are documented there, implicitly through how it's using `async_result<>` traits.

A lot more detail is here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html#boost_asio.reference.asynchronous_operations.automatic_deduction_of_initiating_function_return_type

To detect what is a valid completion token, you can use the `completion_token_for` trait: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/library_elements.html

Because the async_result trait takes the completion signature and the completion token might be/wrap a handler for that signature, it may depend on the completion signature given. For some, it won't, e.g.:

```
static_assert(
    asio::completion_token_for<asio::use_awaitable_t<>,
                               void()>);
static_assert(asio::completion_token_for<
              asio::use_awaitable_t<>,
              void(boost::system::error_code, std::size_t)>);
```

But wrapping a callback handler:

```
auto h  = [](boost::system::error_code, std::size_t) {};
auto bh = bind_executor(asio::system_executor{}, h); // wraps handler

static_assert(not asio::completion_token_for<
              decltype(bh), void()>);
static_assert(asio::completion_token_for<
              decltype(bh),
              void(boost::system::error_code, std::size_t)>);
```

See the examples live [On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f051ab0cd2f33f3)